# time difference between two events in a table(SQL)

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

let us suppose I have a table

| Id | event | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | event1 | 3:30 |
| 1 | event2 | 3:30 |
| 3 | event1 | 3:35 |
| 1 | event3 | 3:40 |
| 3 | event3 | 3:50 |
| 1 | event1 | 3:55 |
| 1 | event3 | 3:56 |

Now these events are occurring again and again. I want to write and sql query to calculate all the time difference between two different event for each id. For example, In this if I have to calculate all the time differences between current time of event3 and most recent previous time for event1 for each id. The expected result would be.

| Id | event1 time | event3 time | difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3:30 | 3:40 | 10 |
| 3 | 3:35 | 3:50 | 15 |
| 1 | 3:55 | 3:56 | 1 |

The events will occur again and again and the table can contain n number of other events between the two events. For all the times event3 occurs, I want to find the most recent time the event1 occurred and then calculate the difference between the two(partitioned by id).

Analogy- this can be compared to a transaction database where the events are transaction events for a particular person(id). I want to have a table which gives time difference between all the times two events(for eg recieved amount,paid amount) occured for that particular person.

I will be running this query on spark since my data is huge therefore I want to avoid joins.
Can I somehow use window functions(lag,last_value) etc for this? I am having trouble selecting the previous event1 for the current event3.

Comment: `all the time differences between current time of event3 and most recent time for event1` here is one point to clarify, only previous `event1`? or any `event1`, what if you got this  `event1 : 3:30, event3 : 3:40, event1 : 3:41` which `event1` should I compare?

Comment: @T.Peter only the previous one

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SparkSQL?  These are quite different.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am using SparkSql. Yeah, sorry I will remove mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do can use `lag` but keep in mind this only work with every `event3` got only one paired `event1` otherwise this query will break. so there will be a better solution,but just for this one case:

```
select id,l_time event1time,time event3time,(time-l_time) as diff from (
  select id,event,
  lag(event) over(partition by id order by time) l_event,
  time,
  lag(time)over(partition by id order by time) l_time 
  from [table]
  where event in('event1','event3') )a
where event = 'event3' and l_event = 'event1'
```

also in pseudo data I use `int` for time column, so there might be a slight tweak to get time difference.
here is [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d7ddca85465093abb68c0a881b6a11e8) for beter examine.

Comment: Thanks but could you please elaborate on "this only work with every event3 got only one paired event1 otherwise this query will break".

Answer (score 0):

SparkSQL doesn't have a time data type, so I have to assume that the `time` column is a string.  That means you need to convert it to numbers.

So, your question is several rolled up into 1:

- How to handle multiple id/event pairs?
- How to pivot the data into separate columns?
- How to do the subtraction?

For the first, I'll enumerate the id/event pairs.  For the second, conditional aggregation.  And for the third, string splitting wizardry:

That would be:

```
with t as (
      select id,
             max(case when event = 'event1' then time end) as event1_time,
             max(case when event = 'event3' then time end) as evente_time
      from (select t.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by id, event order by time) as seqnum
            from mytable t
           ) t
      group by id, seqnum
     )
select t.*,
       ((split(event3_time, ':')[0] * 60 + split(event3_time, ':')[1]) -
        (split(event1_time, ':')[0] * 60 + split(event1_time, ':')[1])
       ) as diff
from t;
```